# MongoDB: How do I sum up a unique field in $group aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following dataset after completing some aggregation magic:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb", "comment" : { "commentor" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1", "id" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922aa1")}, "max" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922aa3")}
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb", "comment" : { "commentor" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e6", "id" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922aa2")}, "max" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922aa3")}
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb", "comment" : { "commentor" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1", "id" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922aa3")}, "max" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922aa3")}
```

The _id represents a post and in the post, there are comments. In this case, there are 3 comments; 2 by the same commentor (`"56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1"`) and one by another commentor (`"56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e6"`).

I want to write an aggregation query that would count up all the unique comments by commentor (`"56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1"`) only  and return that the commentor commented twice on post `"5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb"`.

I tried the following:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "count" : { "$sum" : "$comment.commentor" } } }
```

The results were:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb", "count" : 0 }
```

Please note that I'm not trying to count up **all** the comments by all the commentors in that post so I'm not trying to do this:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
```

Would result in:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb", "count" : 3 }
```

I just want the count of post by user (`"56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1"`)

**EDIT:**

After some research, I see that $sum only works on numeric fields and not non-numeric fields: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum

Is there any way I can get the number of comments posted by user (`"56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1"`) per post `"5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb"`?

Comment: It's not possible to have duplicate `_id`  field within a collection. Also you never said what your result should look like.'

Comment: Maybe i should have made it clearer but the dataset at the beginning is actually after aggregation which is why the _id looks duplicated.

Comment: Can you show the initial data? Perhaps there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Its ok, I have already come up with a working solution - see my answer below and the result of the query showing what i want to achieve.

Comment: The problem is the data has multiple layers of aggregation so if I show the initial data, it will just be confusing. I just showed the data at the level before i wanted to count up all the unique values for a specific user to keep the question simple.

Comment: I've seen your answer and I can tell that you're doing it wrong because  it seems like you use `$unwind` some array in your pipeline.  Anyway if you are ok with what you got then fine.

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit of trial and error, I managed to figure it out.

```
group2 = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "count" : {
            "$sum" : {"$cond" : [ {"$eq" : ["$comms.c", "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1"] }, 1 ,0 ] }
        }
    }
}
```

We are summing up the 1's on condition that `comms.c` equals to user `"56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1"`.

Result:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb", "count" : 2 }
```